# What the method should I use when collectionview and button in the same view in IOS?

Tags: ios, view, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to IOS , and I use the Xcode5.

I want to create a view like the following picture.

[image]

Can I add a `View` , and add the `button` and the `collectionView cell` in to the `View` , and add the `imageView` and two `label` which below the `imageView` in to `collectionView cell` ?

or does there has other method to implement the view like the picture ?

---------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------

I have modify the `xib` file like the following picture.

[image]

I add the `collectionView` below two `button` , but how to add the `label` below image like the following first picture ?

Comment: Use the UICollectionViewController and do some stuff to get in this way..

Comment: do you want a collection view of images.. and on each button click a new cell with image gets added?? is that your question

Comment: No , it will change to other page when the button click. The question is how to implement the view like the picture ?

Comment: Hi @Martin add UIViewController instead UICollectionViewController then in view add two button at top and then collection view.When click on button reload collection view.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the top two buttons to the collectionView headerView using following method

```
 // The view that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"headerView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
         [headerView addSubview:YOURBUTTON1];
         [headerView addSubview:YOURBUTTON2];
       }
  return headerView;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement it like you want fairly easily.

You have a couple of options, you can either use a `UICollectionView` and just pop it where you want it to go on top of your `UIViewController` along with the buttons.

The other option is to use a `UIContainerView` to contain your `UICollectionViewController` and manage it through the corresponding view controller to manage the data/delegate.

luckily I have 2 such examples handy from something I was testing recently.

[image]

Above: `UICollectionView` in a `UIViewController` with the buttons
Below: A `UICollectionViewController` embedded in a `UIContainerView`

[image]

Comment: In the above example , does all the widget in the `view` ? and does the back square is the collectionView ?

Comment: And I add a `View` , but it can not add the `collectionView cell` in to the View ? How do I add the collectionView with label ?

Comment: A `CollectionViewCell` can be put into a `CollecctionView` object in the screenshots above the cyan square is a `CollectionViewCell` inside a `CollectionView` (black square). In the second, the long white rectangle and the square with Label written in it are two different instances of `CollectionViewCell`

Comment: I have edit the content , and I don't understand how to add the `label` and `image view` into `collectionView`. Please help me , Thanks!

Comment: Edit the collectionView cell to have a label to it